How to Display Live Preview of Running Tests Using Selenium/Node Container's noVNC Feature
Using selenium/node-docker and selenium/hub how can I access to the novnc live preview displayed on http://<node-ip>:7900?autoconnect=1&resize=scale&password=secret
here's my docker-compose
version: "3"
services:
  node-docker:
    container_name: node-docker
    image: selenium/node-docker:4.21.0-20240522
    volumes:
      - ./assets:/opt/selenium/assets             #For video recordings
      - ./config.toml:/opt/bin/config.toml        #Mount configuration file
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock #Grid to run docker commands
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - SE_VNC_VIEW_ONLY=1
      - SE_VNC_NO_PASSWORD=1

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.21.0-20240522
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"

  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: ./app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"

and here's the config.toml used by selenium/node-docker to build the nodes
[docker]
# Configs have a mapping between the Docker image to use and the capabilities that need to be matched to
# start a container with the given image.
configs = [
    "selenium/standalone-chrome:4.21.0-20240522", '{"browserName": "chrome"}'
]

host-config-keys = ["Dns", "DnsOptions", "DnsSearch", "ExtraHosts", "Binds"]

# URL for connecting to the docker daemon
# Most simple approach, leave it as http://127.0.0.1:2375, and mount /var/run/docker.sock.
# 127.0.0.1 is used because internally the container uses socat when /var/run/docker.sock is mounted 
# If var/run/docker.sock is not mounted: 
# Windows: make sure Docker Desktop exposes the daemon via tcp, and use http://host.docker.internal:2375.
# macOS: install socat and run the following command, socat -4 TCP-LISTEN:2375,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/docker.sock,
# then use http://host.docker.internal:2375.
# Linux: varies from machine to machine, please mount /var/run/docker.sock. If this does not work, please create an issue.
url = "http://127.0.0.1:2375"
# Docker image used for video recording
video-image = "selenium/video:ffmpeg-6.1.1-20240522"

# Uncomment the following section if you are running the node on a separate VM
# Fill out the placeholders with appropriate values
#[server]
#host = <ip-from-node-machine>
#port = <port-from-node-machine>

all I want is to display the live test in my app but I couldn't get it working I even tried directly through the novnc websocket binary messages in ws://0.0.0.0:4444/session/<session_id>/se/vnc but things where too complicated.
Any help please ?

The port for noVNC on the selenium/node-docker has not been exposed.
To use noVNC the selenium/node-docker has to be configured to assign the default noVNC port of the container (7900) to any local / host port.
Also for an image that contains a browser, use the flag --shm-size=2g to use the host's shared memory (based on the question above, that is selenium/standalone-chrome:4.21.0-20240522).
See the amended docker-compose.yml below:
    version: "3"
    services:
      node-docker:
        container_name: node-docker
        image: selenium/node-docker:4.21.0-20240522
        shm_size: 2gb
        volumes:
          - ./assets:/opt/selenium/assets             #For video recordings
          - ./config.toml:/opt/bin/config.toml        #Mount configuration file
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock #Grid to run docker commands
        depends_on:
          - selenium-hub
        environment:
          - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
          - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
          - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
          - SE_VNC_VIEW_ONLY=1
          - SE_VNC_NO_PASSWORD=1
        ports:
          - "7900:7900" #Expose noVNC port

      selenium-hub:
        image: selenium/hub:4.21.0-20240522
        container_name: selenium-hub
        ports:
          - "4442:4442"
          - "4443:4443"
          - "4444:4444"
    
      app:
        container_name: app
        build:
          context: ./app
        ports:
          - "5000:5000"

Recreate the your grid and then you should be able to access the noVNC like you did previously via http://<node-ip>:7900autoconnect=1&resize=scale&password=secret
Also, the noVNC preview can be accessed via teh Selenium Grid UI, by going to the Sessions tab, then click on video icon next to session id.

The chrome node is the one that I need to expose because we are talking about different ips/containers, for exmaple if the node-docker (172.22.0.3) create the chrome-node(172.22.0.4) in this case the preview will be accessible via http:/172.22.0.4:7900autoconnect=1&resize=scale&password=secret.  And since I am using conf.toml for node-docker to function I cannot expose 7900 of the standalone-chrome container
